# Keeping progress of the letters guessed in hang man python

Tags: python, user-interface

```
Graphics=['''
------------
|         |''','''


------------
|         |         
|          O''','''


------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / ''','''

------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / |''','''


------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / | 
|          | ''','''


------------
|         |
|          O 
|         / |
|          |
|         /  
|
|            ''','''


------------
|         |
|          O 
|         / |
|          |
|         / | 
|
|            ''']



import random

class Hangman():

    def Playing(self):
        listOfWords = ["example", "says", "python", "rocks"]

        again = True
        while again:

            guessWord = random.choice(listOfWords)
            board = "*" * len(guessWord)
            alreadySaid = set()
            mistakes = 7

            print(" ".join(board))

            guessed = False
```

## These are the guesses I want to keep track of

```
            while not guessed and mistakes > 0:

                whatplayersaid = input("Guess a letter: ")

                if whatplayersaid in guessWord:
                    alreadySaid.add(whatplayersaid)
                    board = "".join([char if char in alreadySaid else "_" for char in guessWord])
                    if board == guessWord:
                        guessed = True
                else:
                    mistakes -= 1
                    print("Nope.", mistakes, "mistakes left.")
                    print("Letters Guessed:",guessed)
```

## This is where my mistake is.

```
                    print(Graphics[6-mistakes])






                print(" ".join(board))

            again = (input("Again [y/n]: ").lower() == 'y')

Hangman().Playing()
```

> I want to keep progress of the guessed letters, and print them every guess. How do I do that?, what I have now returns only the last incorrect guess

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is not print the `print(Graph)` This prints the location of the Graph array. You need to print something like:

```
print(Graph[7-mistakes])
```